# How to change a marker base in mapbox gl?

Tags: mapbox, geojson, marker, mapbox-gl

When I add a marker to my mapbox gl script, it's positionned in a way that its center indicates the location, not the base. As a consquence, the marker seems to indicate an incorrect location.
[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQeNj.png)

Is there a way to change the part of the image that is used as the base for the coordinates?

Thanks in advance!
Oktawia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [icon-offset layout property](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layout-symbol-icon-offset) to offset the icon from your coordinates

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "pointclick",
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'pointclick',
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}",
        "icon-size":1,
        "icon-offset": [0, -13]
    },
    "paint": {}
});
```